# Bash ignore error and get return code

Tags: bash

I am using `set -e` to abort on errors.

But for particular one function I want to ignore error and on error I want return code of the function.

Example:

```
do_work || true 
 if [ $? -ne 0 ] 
  then
   echo "Error"
  fi
```

But it is not work return code is always true due || true

How to get return code on do_work on error ?

Comment: Why don't you disable exit on error just before that call?

Comment: @Mat ya that will work thanks. But for knowledge purpose is there a way I can capture return code ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
do_work || {
    status=$?
    echo "Error"
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Several of the answers given here are not correct, because they result in a test against a variable that will be un-defined if `do_work` succeeds.

We need to cover the successful case as well, so the answer is:

```
set -eu
do_work && status=0 || status=1
```

The poster's question is a little ambiguous because it says in the text "on error I want return code" but then the code implies "I always want the return code"

To illustrate, here is problematic code:

```
set -e

do_work() {
    return 0
}

status=123

do_work || status=$?
echo $status
```

In this code the value printed is 123, and not 0 as we might hope for.

Comment: and what about "ignore error" part of the question?

Comment: It does exactly what I want: capturing the original exit code while sending a 0 exit code at the end of the command

Comment: @jangorecki the "ignore error" part is implicit by using the `&&` (AND operator). Its right-hand operand must be executed in any case (to ensure that both operands are _true_). If `do_work` succeeds, then `status=0` is executed and the `||` lazy-evaluation will not execute `status=1` If it fails, the `&&` expression fails `||` will have to run `status=1` in order to know if the right-hand operand will make the `||` expression evaluate to _true_ (given than the first operand evaluated to _false_ (because of failure of first `&&` operand).

Answer (score 8):

You could use a subshell shortcut:

```
( set +e; do_work )
 if [ $? -ne 0 ]
  then
   echo "Error"
  fi
```

Hope this helps =)

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use a pipe, `-e` only looks at the right-most result of a pipe:

```
set -e

do_work | true

retn=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
if (( $retn != 0 ))
then   
    echo "Error $retn"
fi     
echo Ending
```

I wrote a simple `do_work` which just did `exit 42` and got the following output:

```
Error 42
Ending
```

The `PIPESTATUS` array is maintained by Bash, with each element giving the return code of each part of the pipeline.  We need to capture it at once (hence `$retn`) since it is overwritten at each command.

Of course this might be problematic if your `do_work` includes a pipe itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
do_work || status=$?
if [ $status -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "Oh no - Fail whale $status has arrived"
fi
```